# What can I delete from UEFI boot partition?

Tags: boot, uefi

Bought a new machine, a fanless server type, and I have installed Arch Linux successfully. It boots, runs daemons, etc.

The machine came with a (probably pirated) copy of Windows installed. What can I delete from the `/boot` directory (which is what `/dev/sda1` is mounted on)? I'm never going to boot Windows on this machine again, I've already overwritten it.

There's a bunch of files under `/boot/Boot/` that look like unnecessarily fancy Windows bootloader things, fonts, "resources", `memtest.exe`. There's also a directory `/boot/EFI/Microsoft/` that looks totally extraneous for a Linux machine. Can I delete all of those files?

Comment: What research have you already done? What was unclear and requires guidance? Did you look into the UEFI protocol/standard documentation? Have you searched for guidance and found unclear or incorrect answers?

Comment: @0xSheepdog - googled for it, searched on this stackexchange, looked in Arch Linux wiki, looked in Arch linux forums. Found nothing except *keeping* Windows stuff for dual boot. Now, got an answer for the question? Arrogance like this is why asking on stack exchange is a last resort for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the best thing to do is re-format the partition and then do a boot repair from the Arch install disk; or, you can remove everything that looks like it does not belong from the boot partition (as you have identified some), and in the worst case, do a boot repair iif you break it.

Comment: Since "do a boot repair" was part of the process one way or the other, I chose to delete the obvious Microsoft leftovers. That actually worked, as the machine has rebooted after deleting a ton of files.